# Given a list of tuples that consist of 2 teams in a tuple, return a list that is sorted from winning team to losing team

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
matches = [("Team D","Team A"), ("Team E","Team B"), ("Team T","Team B"), ("Team T","Team D"), ("Team F","Team C"), ("Team C","Team L"), ("Team T","Team F")]
```

Take the first tuple for example `("Team D", "Team A")`, since `D` is before `A` in the tuple, `D` wins over `A`. In the situation 2 teams do not play against each other, we determine the winning order this way: For example if we want to find out the winning order between `T` and `A`, since `D` wins over `A` and `T` wins over `D`, overall `T` wins over `A` as well `T > D > A`.

Define a function `winning_list(matches)` that returns a sorted list of teams e.g. `["Team T", "Team D", "Team A", ...]`

I have a helper method to find the order of winning between 2 specific teams

```
def winner(matches, team_1, team_2):
    size = len(matches)
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    for i in range(0, size): # extract games with team1
        if matches[i][0] == team1 or matches[i][1] == team1:
            lst1.append(matches[i])
        elif matches[i][0] == team2 or matches[i][1] == team2: # extract games with team2
            lst2.append(matches[i])
    lst_partner1 = [] # opponent teams involving team1
    lst_partner2 = [] # opponent teams involving team2
    for i in range(0, len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i][0] != team1:
            lst_partner1.append(lst1[i][0])
        elif lst1[i][1] != team1:
            lst_partner1.append(lst1[i][1])
    for i in range(0, len(lst2)):
        if lst2[i][0] != team2:
            lst_partner2.append(lst2[i][0])
        elif lst2[i][1] != team2:
            lst_partner2.append(lst2[i][1])
    common = [value for value in lst_partner1 if value in lst_partner2] # opponent team that played against team1 and team2
    # print(common)
    opponent_team = common[0]
    # print(opponent_team)
    if len(common) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for  i in range(0, len(lst1)):
            if opponent_team in lst1[i]:
                idx_opp1 = lst1[i].index(opponent_team)
        for l in range(0, len(lst2)):
            if opponent_team in lst2[l]:
                idx_opp2 = lst2[l].index(opponent_team)

        if idx_opp1 == idx_opp2:
            return 0
        elif idx_opp1 < idx_opp2:
            return 2
        elif idx_opp1 > idx_opp2:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

But this method seems to be ineffective. Also, it will only work if they have a common opponent team they played against.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written to achieve this and error you are getting.

Comment: Could you try to expandera on the problem statement and also provide the expected result given your example

Comment: what if you have [('Team A', 'Team B), ('Team B, TeamA')], who is winning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided about how to rank a solution could be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

matches = [("Team D", "Team A"), ("Team E", "Team B"), ("Team T", "Team B"),
           ("Team T", "Team D"), ("Team F", "Team C"), ("Team C", "Team L"),
           ("Team T", "Team F")]


def winning_list(mathces):
    scores = defaultdict(int)
    for fst, snd in matches:
        scores[fst] += 1
        scores[snd] -= 1
    return sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)


ranking = winning_list(matches)
print(ranking)
```

To make it even simpler we could use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter


def winning_list2(mathces):
    scores = Counter()
    for fst, snd in matches:
        scores[fst] += 1
        scores[snd] -= 1
    return scores.most_common()
```